# How to reclaim unmounted disk space

Tags: arch-linux, disk

I've ended up in a situation where I cut my disk space in half, and would like to merge two partitions together. Here is a picture from Gnome Disks:

[image]

The blue partition on the left is unused, and Partition 7 on the right is what I boot into and currently use. It looks like in Gnome Disks, I can just click the red minus sign to delete the blue, unmounted partition. Is this going to let me combine my two partitions?

Thanks.

Comment: Not really, since you can't backward extend a partition (or filesystem, actually). You will need to move it backward by some means first (including file-based approaches).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions cannot be resized to the left, you actually need to copy all the data from the second partition to the start of the free space and then resize it to the right. GNOME Disks cannot do this, you need to use [GParted](https://gparted.org/) for this and its *Resize/Move* operation. This cannot be done on a mounted filesystem so you'll need to use the LiveCD. Also make sure to make a backup first, this can be potentially dangerous operation (if you for example lose power during the operation, recovery would be really hard).

Comment: Thanks, I'll make a backup and try to spin up an Ubuntu live cd to make the changes.